# Can Group Shell (gsh) use a default host list?

Tags: linux, cluster

Question concerning [gsh](http://guichaz.free.fr/gsh/) - I could not find the information in the man page or on the developers page:

Is there a way to define a default list of hosts to connect to? I do not want to always use the command line parameter to supply a hosts file, nor list the hosts directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know gsh, but you can use this, with a list of hosts in the file "myhosts":

```
gsh $(cat myhosts)
```

Put this in a shell script or shell alias...

Comment: Thanks, will try that as fall-back. If nothing better/more detailed arises, I'll accept that as answer.